# What paint to use for laser engraved (aircraft and not only) panels with backlighting

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have been researching how to make backlit panels for flight simulators, like this one:

[image: Backlit Boeing 737 panel]

I came across this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vf7tQNYqliw

Where they use cast transparent acrylic and then paint it with "laser color", however I cannot find anything on the internet for laser color, laser paint, laser resistant paint whatsoever.

Came across a post in aviation stackexchange, where they also refer to "white opaque special laser colour" (search for "How are backlit aircraft panels (for simulators) made?", I cannot post more than 1 link now).

I tried myself using painted opal acrylic with black and then grey color, but when the laser hits, it burns the paint and damages the acrylic, which gives it smoked appearance when backlighting is off, as opposed to white.

I haven't tried painting white first, because 1. The acrylic is white opal in the first place, and 2. I'm afraid I will have the same result when the laser hits the paint.

Can somebody provide more insight about the technology and the actual products used? What is that laser color they talk about?

Comment: somewhat related question: [Materials and procedures for painting acrylic (Plexiglass) sheet](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/687/materials-and-procedures-for-painting-acrylic-plexiglass-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to disappoint you but I have tried numerous times to contact the makers that created that video and I have yet to get even one reply from them.  It seems they use those terms like, "white opaque special laser colour" in a manner that is deliberately vague; perhaps they have a proprietary paint or formula for mixing they don't want to share with the general community... sorta like the recipe for KFC original recipe chicken. They are a German based firm and I've translated most of what is contained on their website and the terms like "laser colour" have a more literal translation of enamel or varnish.  So it could be that their paint contains a laser reflective varnish they mix into the white paint. It's a bit confusing because they also call that special laserpaint white translucent, not opaque.

Here are links to their site:

- http://www.simparts.de/en/faq.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vf7tQNYqliw&t=60s

Comment: It is not enough if your post is not spam, it shouldn't even seem one.